# Value of radio button

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x;
        x = document.getElementById("numb2").value;
        document.write(x);
    }
    </script>
    ***
    <body>
    <form>
            <input  id = "numb2" value = "Male" type="radio">Male
            <input   id = "numb2" value= "Female" type="radio">Female
    </form>
  </body>
```

The problem is that I'm getting 'Male' whatever I choose.

Comment: IDs have to be unique. If you have duplicates, `getElementById` returns the first one.

Comment: Radio buttons are grouped by their `name`, not their `id`.

Comment: Why would you expect `getElementById` to care which one was selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xoxhk3mf/):

```
 <form>
        <input  name='sex' value = "Male" type="radio">Male
        <input  name='sex' value= "Female" type="radio">Female
 </form>
```

You must use name property to achieve this functionality and loop over all elements to check which radio element is selected, as shown in below code.

```
function myFunction() {
   var value = "NONE";
   var elems = document.getElementsByName("sex");
   for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
       if(elems[i].checked) {
           value = elems[i].value;
           break;
       }
   }
   alert(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a button group by giving both buttons the same `name`. Then you can use `querySelector` to select the chosen element and get its value.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var val = document.querySelector("[name=numb2]:checked").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = val;
  }

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

```html
<input name = "numb2" value = "Male" type="radio">Male
<input name = "numb2" value = "Female" type="radio">Female
<div>
Chosen: <span id="output"></span>
  </div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must add the radio buttons in a group, you can do that with the attribute "name". Let me show you how to do that.

```
<input type="radio" name="groupRadio" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="groupRadio" value="female">Female
```